# How to make a folder in one svn repo inherit from another folder in another svn repo

Tags: svn

I would like to create a folder in our svn repository which inherits from another folder in another repository.How do i do that?
P.s . My folder is intended to act as external , so if the owners of the other repository make some changes in the contents of the parent folder , I have those changes applied to my folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`svn:externals`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/externals/) property for this. The property adds a special link to another location in the same or another Subversion repository.

The externals definitions may be pinned to a certain revision or may always point to HEAD (i.e., the youngest revision).

You can find more information about `svn:externals` on the following pages:

- [SVNBook | Externals Definitions](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/externals/)
- [TortoiseSVN Manual | External items](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html)

For example, check https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#tortoisesvn/view/head/trunk/ext. The directories `apr`, `apr-util`, `serf`, `snarl`, `Subversion`, `TortoiseOverlays` are added via `svn:externals`.

[image]

When exposed to the Subversion client, the externals make it check out the data from the linked repository path into your working copy. You can update, view log, commit into externals and so on.

[image]

**IMPORTANT:** The `svn:externals` property is versioned and is tied to the URL of the repository path or URL you are linking. If the repository you are linking to is hosted on the same server installation, **use repository-relative externals**.

Comment: This was helpful thank you. But what if I already have a folder in **"my repo"** that is linked to **"another repo"** and I want to move this folder to another location in **"my repo"** preserving the linkage?

Comment: You mean that you already have `svn:externals` configured? Then create the same `svn:externals` property in another directory. And remove the old property. Instructions on adding, modifying and deleting `svn:externals` are given in the links in my post.

Comment: In our repo , there is a folder called "common". The ownership and authorization of this folder is for a german company and we don't have any control over it. Inside this folder there are some items that are necessary for our product which is a software. Now , we want to move this folder completely to another location in our repository preserving all the history. We have to also make sure that this "common" folder is still linked to the repository of the german company once we relocate it. This folder is fixed and its properties are svn:ignore , svn:global-ignore, bugtraq:number ,bugtraq:url

Comment: The folder is cannot be deleted and its properties cannot be modified. I tried creating the same properties for a folder with the same name in another location , but it didn't work.

Comment: @RaminB please, check the documentation and try ’svn:externals’ in some testing repository.